# Option for generating getters and setters not showing up on VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[image]

So I'm trying to make a project using Spring Boot and I had been able to use the "Generate Setters/Getters" button before on this same file but for some reason that option is no longer available in the dropdown. Could someone provide an explanation for why this is and what may have happened to this option?

Answer (score 36):

You might be missing the add-on "Java Code Generators" which you can download from the marketplace. I installed this and I was able to generate getters and setters.

The solution posted by Madhu works. I added the image below for anyone to follow along.

[image]

Comment: This screenshot does not show you how to actually open that menu. It would be great if someone could provide a better screenshot.

Answer (score 21):

Try this:
Right click >> Source Action

See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-refactoring) for a list of actions.

1. Right click and select 'Source Action'
   [image]
2. Select 'Generate Getters and Setters...'
   [image]
3. Select fields of class and click ok.
   [image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I figured it out, apparently `import lombok.Data` handles all getters, setters, and other stuff in the background. This had the unexpected result of getting rid of the generate getters/setters option in the dropdown menu. I got rid of this import in the code and the menu option was back.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "Java extension pack" from Microsoft installed. Do this:

-Right Click on the workbench.

-Click on Source Actions:
[VSCODE view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8gac.png)

-Click on "Generate Getter and Setter":
[VSCODE view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzQnu.png)

-Select the attributes to which you want to generate the getters and setters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).